# Fuel/gasoline smell under car. Normal or problem?

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, smell, evap, venza

Is there any normal process or function which could result in some fuel / gasoline smell under the vehicle? Or does this necessarily indicate an issue?

On a 2009 Toyota Venza, I got some whiffs of fuel when under the rear of the car near the charcoal canister, the rear differential (AWD), trunk / spare tire areas. The smell isn't very strong but it is distinctive.

I do not detect any fuel smell from inside the vehicle or when walking or even crouching around the outside of the vehicle, even at the wheel wells or fuel door.

I'm not (yet) familiar with all the details of the fuel and EVAP systems, so I wonder if it is always a totally sealed system or if there are some situations which may result in fumes being vented.

Answer (score 2):

You should not smell gasoline vapors.  Usual causes are leaking fuel cap, leaking fuel tank, leaking fuel lines, leaking fuel filter, or issues with the evap system.

The evap should vent itself into the engine but the charcoal canister can become saturated with gasoline and no longer function properly.

You'll want to find and correct the issue as this can be a fire hazard.

Comment: Hmm.. then I need to investigate, but not sure where to start. The smell is faint and only detected from some spots deep under the car. Fuel cap is fine, no fuel smell there. No external fuel filter on this car. Nothing dripping. Fuel tank looks spotless inside, didn't notice issues externally but obviously can't see all around. Fuel lines are difficult to see and access. There is underbody rust prevention oil everywhere so it's messy and hard to distinguish between leaks and the coating.